# Correct way to save an image in admin and showing it in a template in Django

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am using MySql and Django. I need to select the image route stored in the database, I can't use the `url` property of an ImageField, It must be the route stored in the database.

First of all, this is my configuration in settings:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

MEDIA_ROOT = PROJECT_ROOT + '/archivos/'
MEDIA_URL = '/archivos/'
```

My first try on the model was this:

```
foto = models.ImageField(upload_to = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

And the URL saved on the database was this:

```
/home/developer/project/mysystem/archivos/hombre.png
```

Later I tried this on the model:

```
foto = models.ImageField(upload_to = '')
```

And the new URL is this:

```
./pantalonazul_pXNLcuF.jpg
```

In both cases the image is uploaded to the `MEDIA_ROOT` folder, but when I try to use the URL saved on the database, the image doesn't shows. I am changing the `src` with jquery, I thougth that was the problem, but no, because I putted by hand both URL's in an image, and none of them worked. Also tried this:  `../../archivos/pantalonazul_pXNLcuF.jpg` but produced the same bad results.

When I enter to the admin, it shows this:
[image: Image in admin]

And if I click on that link I get this URL on Address bar:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/archivos/pantalonazul_pXNLcuF.jpg
```

I also tried to use that URL in the image, written by hand on the `src` property, but didn't worked.

As an extra, when I click on the link to get that last URL, I have an error that says that the URL is not registered on the urls.py file, shows me a list of my URL's and at the end says this:

```
The current URL, archivos/pantalonazul_pXNLcuF.jpg, didn't match any of these.
```

What I'm doing wrong? Why I cant get the image? Is something in the settings or where?

P.S.: The folder where I save the images is outside my app folder, is on the "general" folder, or I don't know how to call it, is in the same folder where settings.py is located, the folders are something like this:

```
-MyAppFolder
-MySystem
    -archivos
        -image1.jpg
        -image2.jpg
    -settings.py
    -urls.py
    -wsgi.py
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a partial solution, reading this [Settings Media URL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#media-url) and after it redirected me to this [Servinge files during development](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development).

I'm using the last model, the one with the empty `uploaded_to` and just added the line that the docs recommend on the second link to the `urls.py` file, and also call the image on this way: `../../archivos/image.jpg` but it says that the `urls.py` solution only works for development, not for serving it as a web page/application, so, someone knows how to make it work in a real server? without using `DEBUG=true` on settings?