# An easy way to show images in Django on deployment (DEBUG=false)

Tags: python, django, image

I am using DJango 1.8 and python 3.4.3, and I have been running my app on Debug mode, and found a way to show images inside a directory configured on MEDIA_ROOT, this was my first question and the solution I have found: [How to upload and show images in DJango](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38866687/correct-way-to-save-an-image-in-admin-and-showing-it-in-a-template-in-django). But reading the docs I found that that solution is not suitable for a served app, so, if I stop using "Debug=True" the images will not be displayed, and I have to use one of the options exposed on this link: [Static files on deployment](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/deployment/) but I don't have money to pay another server, I just can pay my hosting on pythonanywhere, and for the option to use the same server for the images, I don't have idea how to automate the `collectstatic` and also don't know how to trigger it when an user uploads a new image.

I have used ASP.NET and PHP5 and I didn't had problems with the images in none of them, so, I have two questions:

1. Is there an easy way to show images URL's?
2. Is there a high risk security problem if I deploy my app with DEBUG=True?

I hope you can help me, because I find this ridiculous, probably is for better security, but it just not make sense for a framework, instead of making the work easier it make it more difficult and stressful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Django runserver is not intended for serving up static files in a production environment. It should be limited to development and testing environments.

If you are intending to use django's runserver to server up static files with DEBUG=False then use the [--insecure flag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#cmdoption-runserver--insecure).

You should never deploy a site with DEBUG = True due to security implications.

Static files and media assets are 2 different things.

#### Static Files

Static files are things like images you created and files that come with 3rd party apps you have installed (e.g. django-cms). These files include images, css and javascript files etc.). So you need to have a settings.STATIC_ROOT for this.

`python manage.py collectstatic` collects static files from different locations and puts them all in a single folder.

#### Media Files

Media files are things the user uploads (e.g. photos, documents etc.). So you have a settings.MEDIA_ROOT for this.  `collecstatic` won't do anything to media files, they will just be there already once the user uploads them.

#### Serving up static and media files in production

Frameworks like Django aren't going to cover automatic production server configuration - that is something else you will have to learn unfortunately.

There are a lot of good guides around e.g. [this one](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04) to help you get started serving media and static files in production.

Regarding server costs, I'm sure you can find a host to give you some free credit, or pay $5/month for a server somewhere... try [lowendbox](https://lowendbox.com/)

Here is a guide from pythonanywhere regarding media and static files: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DjangoStaticFiles/

Comment: I think you give me some important info, I was reading about Static because the docs redirected me there when I was reading about MEDIA_ROOT. I'm actually using MEDIA_ROOT to store the images that the user uploads, but the images were not displayed, until I used this on URL's: `+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`, but I was reading that this line only works on `DEBUG=True`. So, do you know a way to correctly display MEDIA files on a template on DEBUG=False? Or I have to use an external server? I am reading the guide right now, but i think it is for a local server

Comment: Sorry, I didn't noticed about the pythonanywhere link, there's everything that I need. Now I understand, DJango leaves the job of serving files to the web server, and I have to configure my server to do that. I am using apache, and I found how to make it work, and in the link you posted here there's how to let pyhtonanywhere serve the files. Thank you so much :D

Answer (score 2):

1) in urls.py add:

```
(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
                        {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}),
```

and open url http://myhost.com/media/

2) Never deploy a site into production with DEBUG turned on,  DEBUG=True is a security issue,

Comment: That looks nice, I'm going to give it a try, I was using this: `+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)` but it only works for DEBUG=True... And I have two questions, the first, I have to put that inside of `urlpatterns=[ #some URL's  ]` right? And also, I have to add `url` at the beginning of the code you posted?

Comment: Your solution was good, but when I configure `ALLOWED_HOSTS` it stops working, even if `DEBUG` is `True` or `False`. Can you give me a hint of how to configure that? This is the URL that `runserver` asigns: `http://127.0.0.1:8000` and this is my configuration in settings: `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', '127.0.0.1:8000']`. I also tried without the port number.

Comment: I have configured apache, since then it stopped working. Everything works, only the images don't